# Sign in as another user using windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-authentication, microsoft-identity-web

I am writing an intranet net core application that uses windows authentication. There has been a requirement for the administrator to be able to log in as another user to test the assigned roles and permissions of a particular user and the operation of dependent functionality on them. Is it possible to implement such a solution? Will plugging in Microsoft Identity and using signinmanager solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the windows authentication is worked before the request send to the application. It happened at IIS level. So there is no codes in asp.net core which could let the user log out.

If your administrator wants to be able to log in as another user to test the assigned roles and permissions, the only way is open the browser and use the inprivate window and change the IE browser settings as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. I thought there was some other way out without giving the user password as is the case when using Microsoft Identity.

Comment: Do you mean you want to write some codes in another application to send request to the windows server without using the browser? In my opinion, if you want to use browser, there is no code that could let you log out with the windows authentication.